# Will my current Chinese visa (2023) still be valid if I renew my UK passport?

Tags: visas, china, uk-citizens

I have a UK passport which will expire in May 2023 along with my current Chinese Visa. I was hoping to return to the UK and renew my passport as travel restrictions are getting easier. There have been a lot of recent changes in China regarding international travelling which is why I've asked this question, to see if there is more recent information that can be provided.

My question is, if I renew my British passport will I still be able to return to China with my current visa in my old passport? Or does it become invalid?

Any advice or information regarding this will be super helpful!